# Storing a large set of relational data in a JS Electron Desktop app?

Tags: javascript, sql, json, electron

I am building a Bookmark app using JavaScript and the Electron framework http://electron.atom.io/ to package it as a desktop application.

It is my first time working with Electron and NodeJS as I am a PHP developer.

The image below show the basic concept of my sidebar which will load bookmark tags and when a tag is clicked will then load all bookmarks that belong to that tag.

A tag could potentially have thousands of bookmarks!  For this reason I will maybe do some sort of paging for the bookmarks in the tag sidebvar list.

As a PHP dev I generally use MySQL or SQLite to store my data.

As this will run on a Windows system and maybe a Mac/Linux I want to store the data on the computer and require no remote API server.

I started by using JSON files howeer due to the size of bookmarks in some list, I am not sure this will be the best approach.

What can I store my relational data in on the users computer in the Electron app?

[image]

Comment: check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220970/electron-app-with-database

Comment: Even thousands of bookmarks would take up an insignificant amount of memory if you're just storing the title & description of each bookmark. Your issue is going to be displaying them on screen in an efficient manner, you'll need to use some kind of virtualized list element/component that can render just the visible subset of bookmarks.